# (SQL) Cada imóvel tem várias imagens e uma imagem de capa

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Suponha que eu tenha uma tabela de Imóveis em que um imóvel pode ter várias imagens.

Tenho, portanto, outra tabela, Imagens, com a url.

Tenho, também, uma tabela intermediária que faz o relacionamento N:N entre Imóveis e Imagens.

Caso eu queira que um imóvel, além das imagens, tenha uma imagem de capa, qual é a maneira mais correta de eu criar esse campo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma coluna "Capa" na sua tabela Imagens, de um tipo booleano.
Assim poderá indicar que aquela é a imagem de capa, inclusive mais de uma se for fazer um slide show. Na sua aplicação você define a regra para quando deve exibir a imagem de capa ou não.

Outra abordagem é adicionar uma coluna na sua tabela Imóvel que será uma FK para a tabela Imagem indicando qual das imagens será a de capa. Mas deixe essa constraint como nullable. Caso contrário você já teria que ter as imagens cadastradas antes mesmo de criar o registro inicial para o imóvel.

Comment: Obrigado, Leandro, vou utilizar a segunda abordagem. Também havia pensado nessa possibilidade, mas queria saber a opinião de quem sabe mais do que eu, vai que surgia algo diferente. De qualquer forma, ajudou ou deu mais confiança.